# find the length of aray within array

Tags: php, arrays

my array is like array (size=9)

```
0 => int 0
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => int 4
      2 => int 8
  2 => int 0
  3 => 
    array (size=3)
      1 => int 2
      2 => int 6
      3 => int 10
  4 => 
    array (size=2)
      1 => int 1
      2 => int 5
  5 => 
    array (size=3)
      1 => int 3
      2 => int 7
      3 => int 11
  6 => int 0
  7 => int 0
  8 => int 0
```

now i m trying to get the not of items in each position as in it shud return 1 at key 0 ,it shud return 2 (size of array is 2) at key 1,...but i keeo getting error "count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements "

below is my code

```
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
 $count1=count($books[$i],1);

 for($j=0;$j< $count1;$j++){
 $count2=count($authors[$j],1);
 echo $count1."<br>".$count2;

 }
 }
```

Comment: just check if the variable is an array or instance of countable, that error will occur if what you're trying to `count` is an int in the current iteration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because 0, 6, 7, 8 is not an array so you have to check if it is an array or not. So i added a check in your code:

```
for($i=0;$i<9;$i++){
    $count1= is_array($books[$i]) ? count($books[$i],1) : 1;

    for($j=0;$j< $sourcecount;$j++){
      $count2 = is_array($authors[$j]) ? count($authors[$j],1) : 1;
      echo $count1."<br>".$count2;
     }
 }
```